# I want my player to die when he touches multiple objects with different tags

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I make my player die when he touches two different gameObjects with the different tags. The player should die when he touches "enemy" tag and "ground" tag. Also, I am not trying to use the same enemy tag for ground objects because I'm already using "enemy" tag for my other script.

```css
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move2d : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float playerSpeed;  //allows us to be able to change speed in Unity
    public Vector2 jumpHeight;
    public bool isDead = false;
    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    private Score gm;

    void Start()
    {
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        gm = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("gameMaster").GetComponent<Score>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (isDead) { return; }
        transform.Translate(playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);  //makes player run

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))  //makes player jump
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(jumpHeight, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("ground")) // this will return true if the collision gameobject has ground tag on it.
        {
            isDead = true;
            rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            GameController.Instance.Die();
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if( col.CompareTag("coin"))
        {
            Destroy(col.gameObject);
            gm.score += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OnCollisionEnter will be individually called once for every object that starts touching your player during that frame.

You will need to create a way to track over multiple call to OnCollisionEnter the group of objects touching your player at that point. One way is to create a boolean for each type of tag you are checking:

```
private bool touchedGround = false;
private bool touchedEnemy = false;

private void LateUpdate() {
   touchedGround = false;
   touchedEnemy = false;
}

private void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision) {
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("ground")) {
        touchedGround = true;
    }

    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("enemy")) {
        touchedEnemy = true;
    }

    if (touchedGround && touchedEnemy) {
       isDead = true;
       rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
       GameController.Instance.Die();
    }
}
```

At the end of each OnCollisionEnter you are verifying whether or not both tags have been encountered. In LateUpdate you reset the flags to false, so that the next frame you recheck.

As a side note, this solution is not very extensible. You may wish to use layers (LayerMask) and a bit of boolean logic allowing you to compare multiple categories in one operation. But that would be a different question.

Comment: Maybe add some Debug.Logs to the above code to make sure that OnCollisionEnter2D is indeed being called, and that the objects have the right tags.

Comment: @kevernicus This is perfect, only you shouldn't set bools off in the Late Update because this way those two will never be true, maybe idk.. I haven't tested, but I guess. Of course, if the person asking the question wants only when both tags collide with the player.

Comment: @NikolaG. I see your point. The solution will work but it will probably be very unlikely that both objects *enter* the collision in the same frame (especially if the player is already grounded). I've modified the code to rather use `OnCollisionStay2D`

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have asked the question wrong, and that you mean the player will die if he hits to ground or an enemy, rather than both at the same time. An easy fix is doing as Nikola suggested with a minor change:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("ground") || collision.gameObject.CompareTag("enemy"))
    {
        isDead = true;
        rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        GameController.Instance.Die();
    }
}
```

Comment: True, this works. I've also updated my original answer so that it covers the case when you need only both gameObjects to have a collision with the player. Answer was based on kevernicus answer on this question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following approach, it's called when Enemy || Gound Tag enters && exits.

```
private bool enemy, ground;

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
    {
        enemy = true;
    }

    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
    {
        ground = true;
    }

    if(enemy && ground)
    {
        Debug.Log("Enemy and Ground collision");
    }
}

private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
    {
        enemy= false;
    }

    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
    {
        ground = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This script will only work if the object has both the `ground` tag AND the `enemy` tag.

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work , my player is still alive after he touches the enemy, should I do a new script? ( my enemy has the tag enemy!)

Comment: @FantasmicGalaxy True, my fault. I've edited my answer on a way that will correspond to this question.

Comment: @NikolaG. On reflection after seeing your comment on my answer, your solution would suffer the same problem: the object would need to *enter* into collision in the same frame (unlikely). You would need to move the condition `if (enemy && ground) { ...` into `Update`.

Comment: @kevernicus That's not going to happen. As soon as something collides with the player, the particular bool will become active and will stay active as long its gameObject is colliding with the player. So if the player is colliding with the Ground tag for the most of its time, whenever it collides with the enemy, then `if (enemy && ground)` will be true and thus it will fulfill the question needs. About the `Update`, there is no need to check that condition on every frame. For me, that's considered as a bad practice, instead, my way will be checking the condition only when gameObjects collide.

Comment: @Nikola G. You are absolutely right. Forget what I said :-)

Comment: @kevernicus I enjoyed the conversation, so, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hello why not just do this

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    switch (collision.gameobject.tag)
        case "tag_here"
           isDead = true;
           rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
           GameController.Instance.Die();
           break;
       case "tag_here2"
           isDead = true;
           rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
           GameController.Instance.Die();
           break;
       case "tag_here3"
           isDead = true;
           rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
           GameController.Instance.Die();
           break;
       //Copy paste as long as you need more
    }
```

switch statements are like shorter version of if statements.

Comment: it doesn't work , gives me 3 errors , should I add any Unity system at the top?

Comment: ummm did you not change the "tag_here" strings? you should change it to the tag of the object you wanted to collide. If this is not the case could you please state the 3 errors? Also sorry for late reply